# Chai: throwing error on async/await when no parameter is passed

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, chai

I am trying to test my code (Typescript) and it should throw when no parameter is passed

```
getID(ID) { if(!ID){throw new Error('stop js')} ....}

it('should fail if no ID', async () => { 

    expect(async () =>  await myService.getID() ).to.throw("stop js");
})
```

Based on the documentation the above should work however when I run the test I get

```
 1) myTest
   should fail if no groupId is passed:
 AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

Comment: Have you tried `expect(async () =>  await myService.getID() ).to.eventually.throw("stop js");`?

Comment: TypeError: [Function] is not a thenable. thhis is what I get

Answer (score 1):

You are operating on Promises; `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for Promises as well.

When you run code like this:

```js
it('should fail if no ID', () => { 
    expect(/* not async */ myService.getID()).to.throw("stop js");
});
```

...the call to `getID` will *synchronously* throw an Error. However, when you run code like this:

```js
it('should fail if no ID', async () => { 
    expect(async () =>  await myService.getID()).to.throw("stop js");
});
```

...the call to `async` will pass a Promise into `expect`, which will *asynchronously* be rejected with your Error.

As mentioned by NineBerry in the comments, you can install and use the library [chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) to operate on  Promises:

```js
return expect(async () => await myService.getID()).to.eventually.throw("stop js");
// or
return expect(async () => await myService.getID()).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith("stop js");
```

You will either need to `return` the result of `expect`, or `await` it; otherwise your test will not wait for the `expect` result before determining whether it succeeds.

Comment: I installed chai-as-promise but I get a 'Error: Invalid Chai property: eventually'

Comment: With this solution I get I get TypeError: [Function] is not a thenable.